# trigger to concatenate column by group into new table

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a trigger that concatenates a column of a table by id and inserts it into a new table. When ever a update,insert,delete fires on Table A, it will group by id and concatenate column1 and insert it into Table B.

The problem is that when the trigger fires, Oracle throws the exception mutating table. This is because the trigger runs the query:

```
delete from tableb where id = :id;
insert into tablea (id, col1)
select id, wm_concat(col1) from tablea group by id
```

How do I fix this using triggers? (cannot use stored procedure and would like to avoid using a scheduled task).

Comment: Can you use a Materialized View?

Comment: Whenever you perform a DML operation on `tablea` you also insert into `tablea`?

Comment: Do you mean `insert into tableb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "How do I fix this using triggers? (cannot use stored procedure and
>   would like to avoid using a scheduled task)."

There is no way to do this using just triggers.

You can't use row level triggers, because as you've discovered, the select throws the mutating table exception.

You can't use table level triggers, because we can't reference :NEW or :OLD values in them.

It would be possible to pass the :NEW or :OLD values to the table level trigger by populating a namespace variable in the row level triggers but contexts require a stored procedure, which you say you can't create.

How about a table?  Would you be allowed to create a table to pass the affected ID?

But it is a lot of overhead just to implement a nasty piece of functionality.  The ORA-04091 exception is almost always indicates a flaw in the data model, and that would certainly seem to be the case here.

Comment: So the only way is to create a new table and have a row level trigger insert the affected IDs into it. Then have a table level trigger that processes the id right?